# ROS2 for Win32 (x86): How to make colcon call cmake without "Win64"?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, ros-crystal, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

for a couple of days now, I've been trying to compile ROS2 for x86 under Windows. Because of other dependecies, I can't use x64. I tried a lot of stuff on my Windows 10 64bit machine that didn't work (i.e. recompile all necessary stuff for x86 and so on).

Now I'm working in a vanilla Windows 10 32bit VM and one problem seems to be, that I colcon always calls cmake with "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" and I can't change that. I tried calling colcon witn "--cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32" which did not work either.

What I did on the vanilla Win10 32bit VM:

- install all prerequisites in: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Windows-Install-Binary
- do all the steps from here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Windows-Development-Setup/
- (of course I installed 32bit versions of OpenSSL, Qt, and compiled a 32bit version of OpenCV).

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to compile ROS2 for Win32?
2. How do I make colcon call cmake with "Visual Studio 15 2017" without "Win64"?

Thank you very much

Marossa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324217/ros2-for-win32-(x86):-how-to-make-colcon-call-cmake-without-%22win64%22?/) by [marossa](https://answers.ros.org/users/41895/marossa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll likely need to modify colcon. It has a hardcoded list of supported visual studio versions.

https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake/blob/14ccfdc4aab94e2376d46c3906d7fc5d0c797c4b/colcon_cmake/task/cmake/build.py#L147-L162

It seems like it would need an option to change the target platform name https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html#platform-selection . I recommend opening a PR or issue on https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1